# Ultra-strong nanocrystalline metal without transition to superplasticity

Tags: crystals, metals, nanoscience, technology

It is known that a decrease in the grain size of a polycrystalline metal to 1 micron is accompanied by an increase in its strength by several orders of magnitude (**super-strength**)
almost to the theoretical limit (about 1 GPa) - the Hall-Petch law.

With a further decrease in size (below 10 nm), this **super-strength** is replaced by **super-plasticity**, when the metal flows even at loads much lower than the usual limiting 10 MPa. Roughly, the property of **superstrength** is explained by the smallness of the grain compared to the characteristic size of the dislocation (about 1 μm). The dislocation simply does not fit inside the grain, which means that under load there is no sliding of the crystal lattice along the dislocation (this is the main mechanism of plastic fracture).

The property of **superplasticity** is roughly explained by the “onion” model. In a small grain (less than 10 nm), the applied load removes a layer of surface atoms (layer by layer, like peeling an onion) due to the fact that surface atoms have half as many bonds with neighbors as internal atoms.

Question: is it possible (and if so, how) to obtain a nanocrystalline metal with a grain size noticeably smaller than 10 nm without loss of super-strength, or at least without the appearance of superplasticity?